# Скрипт касательно amocrm forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crm

Есть скрипт типовой

```
</script>
<script id="amoforms_script" async="async" charset="utf-8" src=«https://
forms.amocrm.ru/forms/assets/js/amoforms.js"></script>
```

Необходим чтобы он срабатывал при определенном условии в Rails приложении. Для примера(if Page.slug == "moscow", то... сработать должен скрипт). Подскажите, куда, во-первых, вставляется скрипт и как мне его завернуть в рельсовое условие?
Заранее благодарю всех кто откликнется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас вьюшки на erb? Если да, то в соответствующую вьюху

```
<% if @page.slug == "moscow" %>
  <script id="amoforms_script" async="async" charset="utf-8" src=«https://forms.amocrm.ru/forms/assets/js/amoforms.js"></script>
<% end %>
```